# Sublime Text Package Control - Get More Information

Tags: plugins, sublime-text-2, packages, extension

Is it possible to get more information about the plugin/extension in the Package Control in Sublime Text?

I use the shortcut ctrl + shift + p to bring package control and Install Packages. The information is about two lines per package. Is it possible to get more information so that I can know  before I install it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Package Control website](https://packagecontrol.io). You can search for packages in a number of ways, and view their associated README documents. Other information provided includes version compatibility, links to source on Github or other repositories, links to issues, the ability to donate to the author, package popularity information, including a graph of the number of recent installs, and other details.

Comment: MattDMo, thanks. I know that I can search on the package control website. But I was looking for something that gives just a little more info right in ST, so that I dont have to go back and forth between browser and ST.

Comment: @Cricrazy due to the way Package Control is set up, the only information available within Sublime is the short description of the package, taken from Github or wherever the package is hosted. You can see the short descriptions when you search on Package Control, such as [here](https://packagecontrol.io/search/git). So, unfortunately, the only way to get extended info is to use the website.

Comment: @Cricrazy no problem. If you're interested, Package Control's issues page is [here](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues) if you want to open a feature request to be able to download a package's README file on demand. It shouldn't actually be too difficult to implement, as most of the code already exists for other purposes. Feel free to tag me (same username as here) so I can follow along and perhaps contribute.